# Unable to connect to postgresQL with Ruby

Tags: ruby, postgresql, watir-webdriver, pg, dbd-pg

I've searched in the archive but could not find an answer to my dilemma. I'm coding in Ruby and using watir webdriver framework on my local Mac Yosemite and want to connect to postgres database on a linux box.

I have the required ruby gems installed on my local Mac

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

- dbd-pg (0.3.9)
- pg (0.18.4)
- dbi (0.4.5, 0.4.4)

I am using the following code.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'pg'
require 'dbd/pg'
require 'dbi'
conn = PGconn.connect("10.0.xx.xx","5432",'','',"mydbname","dbuser", "") 
res  = conn.exec('select *  from priorities_map;') 
puts res.getvalue(0,0)    
conn.close if conn
```

On running this 
I a getting these errors

```
.initialize': Could not connect to server: Connection refused (PG::ConnectionBad)

Is the server running on host "10.0.xx.xx" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

If I use the code

```
 dbh = DBI.connect("dbi:pg:mydbname:ipaddress", "user", "")
 row = dbh.exec('select * from etr_priorities_map;') 
 puts row.getvalue(0,0)
 dbh.disconnect if dbh
```

I get the error

```
block in load_driver': Unable to load driver 'pg' (underlying error: wrong constant name pg) (DBI::InterfaceError)  from System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
```

I am new to Ruby. How can I resolve these issues?

Comment: can you telnet to port 5432 on that IP address?  Is postgresql listening on that IP? the first error message is the server denying the connection, nothing to do with your code etc.. Will change that if it isn't listening.

Answer (score 0):

The first error, as @Doon said in the comments, comes from the TCP connection and usually means your database is not listening on the network. Most PostgreSQL packages come with a default configuration that only allows local connections, but you can enable connections over the network in the server configuration via the [listen_addresses](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-LISTEN-ADDRESSES) setting. I installed PostgreSQL through Homebrew on my Mac, and my config is at `/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf`, but if you installed it some other way the path may be different.

The second error is happening because the "driver" part of the connection string [is case-sensitive](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/dbi/DBI#connect-class_method), and the DBD driver for Postgres is named `Pg`, not `pg`. Try this:

```
dbh = DBI.connect("dbi:Pg:mydbname:ipaddress", "user", "")
```

Also, unless you have your heart set on using `Ruby/DBI`, you might want to consider using a more-recently maintained library. Ruby-DBI is very well-written and tested, but it hasn't seen a release since 2010, and Ruby itself has changed pretty significantly in the interim.

If you do want to consider alternatives, I use [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/) for mostly everything, and I highly recommend it, especially for Postgres development, but both [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org/) and [ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) have a large userbase as well.

Comment: I know I am not supposed to say thanks on this fantastic forum but I will still do it. Thanks @Doon and @ Michael. Got all running. Changed the listen_addresses setting to *  .

Comment: Did not know about Sequel. Am starting  with it .

Comment: If it worked, you could accept this answer. That encourages people that answer questions to answer more often. :)